# How can I fix the following error in Xcode: Key Commands must all have a Title, Key, and Selector?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been trying to figure out why I am getting this error: Key Commands must all have a Title, Key, and Selector. Every time I open a new project, this error occurs before I change anything. I have gone in and looked at the source code for Main.Storyboard, but there are no  labels at all. It occurs immediately after creating a new project.

Comment: Do you have any xcode plugins installed?

Comment: No, just Xcode. I am going to try uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode. Will update with the results.

Comment: Have you a recent - Xcode 8? - project you can open? **Preferably after backing up!**

Comment: @dfd Yes, I tried opening one that was working perfectly about a week ago, and the same error is occurring.  Hoping reinstalling will work, have a couple mins left to install.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like uninstalling and reinstalling fixes the issue - most likely a bug in Xcode.